# Match template parameter to template type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

How would I write template or `constexpr` code such that `match` is true only if `Ts` contains an instance of `A`?

```
template <std::uint32_t, int, int>
struct A;

template <typename... Ts>
struct X
{
    constexpr bool match = ???;
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write a trait:

```
template<class> 
struct is_A : std::false_type {};

template<std::uint32_t X, int Y, int Z> 
struct is_A<A<X,Y,Z>> : std::true_type {};
```

Then use it:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct X
{
    constexpr bool match = std::disjunction_v<is_A<Ts>...>;
};
```

See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction) for an implementation of `std::disjunction` in C++11.

Comment: Thanks for introducing std::disjunction :)